# Add counter to Items In List by Key

Tags: c#, list, generics

I have object like this:

```
public class A
{
   public int KeyValue {get; set;}
   public int Counter {get; set;}
}
```

In the main program I have a list on A items
for example:

```
List<A> list = new List<A> {new A{KeyValue  = 1},new A{KeyValue  = 2},new A{KeyValue  = 1},
new A{KeyValue  = 2},new A{KeyValue  = 1},new A{KeyValue  = 3}}
```

I want to add a counter for every item in the list, but for every key I need its own counter.

In the example above it will be:
{1,1},{2,1},{1,2},{2,2}{1,3}{3,1}

I did this code, it works, by I wonder if there is a *"nicer"* one.

```
var grouped = list.GroupBy(a=>a.KeyValue);
foreach (var group in grouped)
{
   int counter = 1;
   foreach (var item in group)
   {
      item.Counter = counter++;
   }
}
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. If you're asking for a Code Review, go to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/, this site is about objective programming problems - if your code works, it's not really a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I will ask there, I didn't know that site before.

Answer (score 1):

If order is not important and this code is not in performance critical part of application you can do some LINQ magic:

```
List<A> list = new[] { 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 3 }
    .GroupBy(i => i)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select((i, index) => new A
    {
        KeyValue = i,
        Counter = index + 1
    }))
    .ToList();
```

Otherwise with latest language version you can clean up code a little bit with [target typed new expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/target-typed-new):

```
List<A> list = new()
{
    new() { KeyValue = 1 }, new() { KeyValue = 2 }, new() { KeyValue = 1 },
    new() { KeyValue = 2 }, new() { KeyValue = 1 }, new() { KeyValue = 3 }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I like the use of SelectMany